# cif file of psi graphene

Tags: graphene

What mysterious properties lie within the crystalline structure of ψ-graphene, the enigmatic 2D carbon allotrope adorned with intricate 5-6-7 carbon ring patterns, that endows it with the crown of the lowest energy and exceptional dynamic and thermal stability among all known carbon variants? How to get the CIF files of psi graphene

Comment: With reference to the paper, https://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/acs.jpclett.7b01364, you could try their procedure of "regularly arranging the carbon skeletons of s-indacene" and relaxing with your DFT package of choice. Or you could try emailing the authors.